# ceiling fan light kit wiring problems

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, light

When I try to add a light kit to my ceiling fan the light seems to short. It is a separate circuit and I checked the wires for the light and they are 120v not 240 I thought maybe I was wiring two hots into the light. I can not seem to figure out what is going on.

I think it uses its own hot from the light switch in the wall but the neutral off the fan. Does this sound correct?

Thanks

Comment: What is the make/model of the fan and what is the make/model of the light kit?

Comment: What does "seems to short" mean? Normally that would trip a breaker.

Comment: How did you wire the fan? A photo of the box above it might help.

Comment: Yeah, wiring fan+light can be tricky. You haven't really given enough information to answer this.  Photos needed of both fan junction box and switch junction box with the switch pulled out for visibility.  Don't unhook anything.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?